# Keep dimensions of a node when scaling UI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have two nodes, a Label and a TextField, inside of a HBox. I want to keep the width of the Label, so when I resize the program it should resize only the TextField, but the opposite happens: the Label is resized, and the TextField keeps the original dimensions.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM7pD.png)

[After (resized)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJRIi.png)

So, what can I do to make the Label non-resizable? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Hgrow properties of the control.

```
HBox.setHgrow(label, Priority.NEVER);
HBox.setHgrow(textField, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Comment: It still resizes at a certain width, but it's better. Thanks